# React Context API with multiple values performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I'm using the React Context API to store many global state values (around 10 and probably more will be needed) and many components are using them. Unfortunately whenever any of the values change, all components using the `useContext` hook have to rerender. My current solution is to use `useMemo` for the return value of the components and `useCallback` for any complex functions and inside custom hooks I have. This addresses most of my performance concerns, but having to use the `useMemo` and `useCallback` all the time is quite annoying and missing one is quite easy. Is there a more professional way to do it?

Here's an example based on my code:

GlobalStateContext.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const GlobalStateContext = React.createContext({ })

export const GlobalStateProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [config, setConfig] = useState({
        projectInfo: ''
    })
    const [projectFile, setProjectFile] = useState('./test.cpp')
    const [executionState, setExecutionState] = useState("NoProject")

    return (
        <GlobalStateContext.Provider
            value={{
                executionState,
                config,
                projectFile,
                setExecutionState,
                setConfig,
                setProjectFile,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </GlobalStateContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default GlobalStateContext
```

Example.jsx

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import GlobalStateContext from '../utils/GlobalStateContext.js'

export default Example = () => {
    const {
        executionState,
        setExecutionState,
    } = useContext(GlobalStateContext)

    return useMemo(
        () => (
            <div>
                The current execution state is: {executionState}
                <br />
                <button onClick={() => setExecutionState('Running')}>Running</button>
                <button onClick={() => setExecutionState('Stopped')}>Stopped</button>
                <button onClick={() => setExecutionState('Crashed')}>Crashed</button>
            </div>
        ),
        [
            executionState,
            setExecutionState,
        ]
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, this problem is unavoidable with context. There is an open [RFC for context selectors](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/119) to solve this, but in the meantime, some workarounds are [useContextSelector](https://github.com/dai-shi/use-context-selector) and Redux, both of which prevent a subscribing component from rendering if the data it's reading did not change.

Comment: Thank you very much for the recommendation, the `useContextSelector` looks very promising and will require waaay fewer changes in my code to incorporate than switching to Redux. You are the best!